# JSON rows Extracting issue in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have following `json` data coming from server in which i want to extract `LimitClass` and `LimitClassID` and store their values in respective arrays.

```
{
    "ErrorDesc":"",
    "ErrorCode":"",
    "LimitClassList":"[{\"LimitClass\":\"L16\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"32900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"28febL0\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"31901\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L14\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"31900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L17\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"32950\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L15\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"31950\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L0\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"21901\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L4\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"23000\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"OTC Send\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"30901\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L2\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"22900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L12\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"28900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L6\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"23900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L1\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"25900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L13\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"29900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L7\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"24900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L8\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"26900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L10\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"27900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L13\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"30900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"UatTesting123\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"32901\\n\"}]"
}
```

Here is the code I have tried :

```
var list = data.LimitClassList;
var arrayLimitClass = [];
var arrayLimitClassId = [];
for(var i in list) {
    arrayLimitClass.push(list[i].LimitClass);
    arrayLimitClassId.push( list[i].LimitClassId);
}
alert(list);
alert(arrayLimitClass);
alert(arrayLimitClassId);
```

List variable has following result when I alert it:

```
[{\"LimitClass\":\"L16\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"32900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"28febL0\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"31901\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L14\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"31900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L17\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"32950\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L15\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"31950\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L0\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"21901\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L4\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"23000\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"OTC Send\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"30901\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L2\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"22900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L12\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"28900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L6\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"23900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L1\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"25900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L13\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"29900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L7\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"24900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L8\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"26900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L10\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"27900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"L13\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"30900\\n\"},{\"LimitClass\":\"UatTesting123\\n\",\"LimitClassId\":\"32901\\n\"}]
```

But I am getting dots (.) when I alert `arrayLimitClass` and `arrayLimitClassId`. What am I doing wrong in extracting rows of `json` Object?

Comment: `var list = JSON.parse(data.LimitClassList)` first.

Comment: You should look into the reason that the server is double-encoding that part of your data structure; there's no good reason for it.

Answer (score 2):

```
"LimitClassList":"[{\"LimitClass\":\"L1....]" 
                 ^                          ^
```

LimitClassList is a string, not an array. Make it so it is an actual array, than your code should work. There should be no reason to have to parse it again.

Comment: what should i do to extract  LimitClassId and LimitClass. And store in arrays

Comment: Easiest thing is to get rid of the string; let it be an actual array, than you will not have to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

The value below `data.LimitClassList` is itself a String containing JSON. You have to decode this first.

```
var list = JSON.parse( data.LimitClassList );
var arrayLimitClass = [];
var arrayLimitClassId = [];

// ...
```

This is more or less a workaround. You should have a look at your server code and fix the encoding error there!